# How to create a second level route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to get the following spec to work. So far I've had some success with making both of these cases work:

- `User/Tasks` -- Lists user's tasks.
- `User/Projects` -- List user's projects.

But how do I get `User/Project/Tasks` to list all the tasks in  the Project (all tasks in project, not just the user's tasks in the project)?

My routes.rb is as following:

```
resources :users do
  resources :tasks, :through => :projects
  resources :projects
end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `:through` option and can't find it documented anywhere.  What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can it not simply be accomplished with?

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end
end
```

Feel free to keep the other route for `:tasks` around .. you'll just have to handle which case it is in your `TasksController`.

Comment: For me, Stackoverflow was always about the little things :) Thanks!